# jQuery file upload script/plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, file-upload

I've been searching the web to find a simple easy script/plugin to do this, the current method I use to achieve the same sort of thing is very messy and takes a lot of script, so It's time for me to find a plugin that will make things much easier. All I need is to have a way to transfer the file from my form (which i already have made), to my php script (which I will also handle myself). I don't want an entire plugin that comes with everything all set up, I just want the bare handler itself if possible.

Comment: if you can use html5, take a look at this tutorial: http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/

Comment: I really can't use html5 as it's not widely supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

Need absolutely no plugin at all. Can POST a form with your file to the server and use PHP to go through your POST'ed data and put it into your data layer.

Comment: I don't want to have to do a page refresh though.

Comment: Then post asynchronously using ajax. e.g. can use jQuery core functionality of jQuery.ajax(options) or whatever preferred way you want to do asynchronous ajax.

Comment: using iframes you can actually. If your file is inside an iframe,  (and the iframe can be invisible or very small), your iframe will refresh after the POST but not your main page. See example: http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/php_ajax_example__asynchronous_file_upload.xml